# Check Box listener on RecyclerView with DataBinding

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

im trying to populate a list of note/message with check box in the item view.

Ive tried set listener unto the checkbox. sadly upon check box click nothing happens.

if i set listener unto the parent view. its able to trigger onClick method. but this will be triggered each time user click the whole  item in the list.

my objectives is more on setting listener for checkbox.

so ill know that user has selected note(s) from the list.

heres my code adapter class together with view holder inner class

```
public class BroadcastRVA extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BroadcastRVA.BroadcastVH>{

private Context mContext;
private ObservableArrayList<MNote> notes;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public BroadcastRVA(Context mContext, ObservableArrayList<MNote> notes, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.notes = notes;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

@Override
public BroadcastRVA.BroadcastVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    NoteListitemBinding binding = NoteListitemBinding.inflate(inflater);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.note_listitem, null);
    BroadcastVH viewHolder = new BroadcastVH(binding, view);
    // create a new view
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BroadcastVH holder, final int position) {
    final  MNote note = notes.get(position);
    holder.cbox.setChecked(note.isSelected());
    holder.cbox.setTag(note);
    holder.vBinding.setNote(note);
    holder.cbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            MNote note = (MNote) cb.getTag();
            note.setIsSelected(cb.isChecked());
            notes.get(position).setIsSelected(cb.isChecked());
            Toast.makeText(
                    v.getContext(),
                    "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() + " is "
                            + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

public ObservableArrayList<MNote> getNotes() {
    return notes;
}
/**
 * Returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter.
 *
 * @return The total number of items in this adapter.
 */
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (notes != null)
        return notes.size();
    else return 0;
}

public class BroadcastVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    NoteListitemBinding vBinding;
    TextView uuid;
    CheckBox cbox;

    public BroadcastVH(NoteListitemBinding binding, View view) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.vBinding = binding;
        this.uuid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id._UUID);
        this.cbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteNote);
    }
    }
}
```

note_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="note"
            type="com.pbasolutions.android.model.MNote" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/deleteNote"
                    android:clickable="true"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewNote"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="@{note.textMsgs}"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:textSize="22sp"/>
                <TableLayout android:layout_column="1">
                    <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textViewNoteDate"
                            android:layout_column="0"
                            android:text="@{note.date}"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:textSize="15sp"/>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="270dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/_UUID"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="@{note._UUID}"
                    android:visibility="invisible"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <View style="@style/Line" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Please paste your note_listitem layout here.

Answer (score 1):

what is NoteListitemBinding ? generally speaking ,onClick method must be triggered when you click the checkbox,when you click the view,the viewgroup will receive the touch event first and then pass the event to its child but if the viewgroup prevent the event,the event will consumed,and child cannot get the event, its onClick method will not be triggered.

Comment: @Ijl5241861   im using DataBinding to bind my data to the view holder.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @ljl5241861 for mentioning on DataBinding, i realized there small silly mistake in my code.. in order to get the child view responds onClick in need to get the view from databinding.getRoot() not the recycler specific one item group view. after change the ViewHolder constructor, by getting the item view via binding.getRoot, i able to trigger the click listener.. hope this helps others as well!!

```
public BroadcastVH(NoteListitemBinding binding, View view) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.vBinding = binding;
        View bindView = binding.getRoot(); 
        this.uuid = (TextView) bindView.findViewById(R.id._UUID);
        this.cbox = (CheckBox) bindView.findViewById(R.id.deleteNote);
    }
```